# Rounding each element in a list to two decimal places

Tags: python, list, decimal

I need help with printing out the list `ty2` to 2 decimals.

`ty2` is a list of table rows  containing `t` and `y` values. The `t` and `y` values have 3 decimals and I need them with 2 decimals. `ty2` values should have 2 decimals. I tried but didnt succees with `print = "%.2f" % (ty2)`

```
print 'Store Data in a Nested List'
print '--------------------'
print 'Task a)' # Task Number
t = [0.000, 0.194, 0.387, 0.581, 0.775, 0.968, 1.162, 1.356, 1.549, 1.743, 1.937] # List      created for t from ball_table2

y = [0.000, 1.656, 2.944, 3.864, 4.416, 4.600, 4.416, 3.864, 2.944, 1.656, 0.000] # List created for y from ball_table2

ty1 = [] # Empty List
ty2 = []
print ' Nested List (ty1)'
for t, y in zip (t, y):
    ty1.append ([t, y])
    ty2.append ([t, y])

import scitools. pprint2 # Imported Pretty Print options
scitools. pprint2.float_format = '% .2f ' # In two decimals

scitools. pprint2. pprint (ty1)

print '--------------------'

print 'Task b)'

print ty2 
"""
Store Data in a Nested List
--------------------
Task a)
Nested List (ty1)
[[ 0.00 ,  0.00 ],
 [ 0.19 ,  1.66 ],
 [ 0.39 ,  2.94 ],
 [ 0.58 ,  3.86 ],
 [ 0.78 ,  4.42 ],
 [ 0.97 ,  4.60 ],
 [ 1.16 ,  4.42 ],
 [ 1.36 ,  3.86 ],
 [ 1.55 ,  2.94 ],
 [ 1.74 ,  1.66 ],
 [ 1.94 ,  0.00 ]]
--------------------
Task b)
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.194, 1.656], [0.387, 2.944], [0.581, 3.864], [0.775, 4.416], [0.968, 4.6], [1.162, 4.416], [1.356, 3.864], [1.549, 2.944], [1.743, 1.656], [1.937, 0.0]]
```

"""

Comment: round(1.656, 2) => 1.66

Comment: You need to loop over the elements of the list and format each one individually. AFAIK, the "%f" format-specifier doesn't work on a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ' Nested List (ty1)'
for t, y in zip (t, y):
    t = '%.2f' % t
    y = '%.2f' % y 
    ty1.append ([t, y])
    ty2.append ([t, y])
```

I just inserted this and this actually solved my problem. Thanks Everyone for contributing <3

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a list that contains tuples of values ( t, y ), you can do the rounding into a new list of tuples in this line:

```
rounded = [ ( round ( a [ 0 ], 2 ), round ( a [ 1 ], 2 )) for a in ty2 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! a lot! I figured it out though :)